# How do I format this java.sql.date?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Can someone please tell me how I can extract the date and time from this?  I'm a java nube!  :-)

Its being sent as XML and when I read the node its in the following format:

For me objDeliveryRoute.getStartTime() is a date in the following format:
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:nn (T in this is for Tango).
Example would be:

2012-04-24T18:41:00

This needs to find a home in an MSSQL Server 2008 db.
Here's the code snippet that I'm suffering with:

```
mydatetime = new java.sql.Timestamp(objDeliveryRoute.getStartTime().toGregorianCalendar().getTime().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class from standard JavaSDK.

Check this code snippet. It makes a java.util.Date instance from string you provided:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    String myDateString = "2012-04-24T18:41:00";
    java.util.Date myDate = df.parse(myDateString);
```

To compose java.sql.Date instance, do the following according to the aforecited code snippet:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
```